# Where to store Spring Boot application-{profile}.properties?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I'm using Spring Boot and several profiles (dev, test, prod). I've configured my application settings now in `application-dev.properties`, `application-test.properties`, and `application-prod.properties`.

The above files are all located in `src/main/resources`, which is not ideal, since now my application will be deployed to production with production configurations, but (while not active) also with the configuration for test and dev.

What is the correct way in Spring Boot to organise these files? I can imagine putting `application-test.properties` in `src/test/resources`, but what about the `application-dev.properties` file?

Comment: I don't use profiles at all. All stages are configured by environment variables.

Comment: I think ideal way would be to store property files on a config server (which could be as simple as a separate git repo) and then load the the files at application startup based on environment.

Answer (score 2):

Spring Boot, out-of-the-box, supports various locations for storing your `application-<profile>.[properties|yaml]` files. As explained in [this section of the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.external-config.files).

1. From the classpath

   - The classpath root
   - The classpath `/config` package
2. From the current directory

   - The current directory
   - The `/config` subdirectory in the current directory
   - Immediate child directories of the `/config` subdirectory

You could even override/add to those directories with specifying the `spring.config.location` property at runtime to your application.

So you don't need to ship them with your application.

Next you also have a myriad of options on how to provide properties for configuration to your Spring Boot application. Files is just one of them, and is explained in [this section of the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#features.external-config). If you add Spring Cloud Config you even get more options as you could also use a centralized configuration server next to the already existing options!.

So instead of providing a file for each environment you could also specify environment variables or provide the information at startup as program attributes. Finally, as deduced from the file location, you could also place the `application-<profile>.[properties|yaml]` next to the jar file instead of inside it and it would be picked up as well. Drawback of the latter is that you need to ship those files next to the jar.

Commonly used, for other then local use, is a config server (or even a key vault) to centralize the configuration.

Answer (score 1):

I understand your question, but you shouldn't be too much concerned about shipping to production with a packaged profile properties that won't be loaded at runtime.

It is how SpringBoot works and any other framework (Quarkus, ...), your application-*.properties files are meant to live there (`src/main/resources`). If your `-test.properties` is not referring a real environment but solely useful for your UTs, then it can be moved to `src/test/resources`.

Comment: I'm not really concerned about it, it's my colleague who is more concerned about it than I am, and I've failed to come up with a great answer so far, but I'm considering to use spring.config.location instead to override -dev.properties

Answer (score 0):

An alternate solution would be to store Dev, QA, Prod environment properties together in a single yaml file like below and can activate the respective environment profile by configuring `spring.profiles.active` property. In this way can at least overcome multiple config files.

**application.yml**

```
logging:
  level:
    org.springframework: ERROR
    com.mkyong: ERROR

spring:
  profiles:
    active: dev
  main:
    banner-mode: off

---

spring:
  profiles: dev
server:
  cluster:
    - ip: 127.0.0.1
      path: /dev1
    - ip: 127.0.0.2
      path: /dev2
    - ip: 127.0.0.3
      path: /dev3

---

spring:
  profiles: prod
server:
  cluster:
    - ip: 192.168.0.1
      path: /app1
    - ip: 192.168.0.2
      path: /app2
    - ip: 192.168.0.3
      path: /app3
```

Comment: Thanks Arun, but this is exactly what I don't want. I want to make sure the production application only has access to the production configuration, and that no dev or test configuration end up in production binary.

Comment: Makes sense Erik, Got it